# Why should we decrement an i variable and use break in a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

What is the purpose of decrementing the "i" variable and using "break" in this function?

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem){
  let newArr = [...arr];
  for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < newArr[i].length; j++){
      if(newArr[i][j] === elem){
        newArr.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data, what is passed as `arr` and `elem`?

Comment: The best way to figure it out is to add breakpoints to your code and trace it out in the debugger. If you don't know how to do that then you should search "js debugging techniques". That said some questions for you. Do you understand what the `splice` function does? How would that affect the `newArr` and it's length? What would happen if `i` was at the second to last character after that was run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by using `newArr.splice(i, 1);` you are removing the current index item from the array, so since all indexes will be moved by -1 for all elements following i at each splice, you then have to reduce i by 1, so you dont skip elements